# How to perform undo operation using Oracle Basic Command

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclecommand

I am new with Oracle Database and I want to know some command relate with Oracle.
Does anyone help me with below questions:
1. Which command use to show undo_retention period?
2. Which command use to show undo tablespace name?
3. how to disable/enable undo Retention guarantee?

Thanks,

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/undo.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Which command use to show undo_retention period?
> 2. Which command use to show undo tablespace name?

Open SQL*PLUS as `SYSDBA` and use `show parameter` command as shown below.

```
SQL> show parameter undo
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
undo_management                      string      AUTO
undo_retention                       integer     2400
undo_tablespace                      string      UNDOTBS1
```

> 3. how to disable/enable undo Retention guarantee?

Now you have the name of the undo tablespace.

Use the following command to switch to undo retention `guarantee`.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE UNDOTBS1 RETENTION GUARANTEE;
```

To switch back to `noguarantee`.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE UNDOTBS1 RETENTION NOGUARANTEE;
```

Use following query to check whether your undo tablespace has retention guaranteed or not.

```
SQL> SELECT tablespace_name, retention FROM dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name = 'UNDOTBS1';
```

For more details: [Managing Undo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/undo.htm#ADMIN013)

Comment: Great! how about Command use to show undo tablespace name? or they 're the same with show undo_retention period?

Comment: Use `show parameter undo_tablespace` on SQLPLUS as sysdba. When we do `show parameter` it runs `like` operator on these parameter tables so we get all related parameters. Example: `show parameter undo` is just like select * from parameters where paramter like '%undo%'.